# Are there shortcuts to show and hide the 3D View header?

Tags: interface, shortcut

What shortcuts will show and hide this panel?

If there aren't any, how can I make them?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

2.8x  .. <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F9</kbd> toggles the header .. <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd> toggles full screen for the area with focus.

In 2.9x, I believe you have to set your own shortcut. (Right-click header > right-click menu item > Add Shortcut).

I set mine back to <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F9</kbd>.
The result can be found in the Keymap preferences here:

[image]

Comment: Thank you!!!!!!

Comment: Hi, this is not working in Blender 2.9x. Is there a hotkey to toggle visibility of the 3D viewport Header in Blender 2.9x? I looked in the Keymap Preferences and didn't find anything. However, even finding the existing hotkeys for the Tools <t> and Sidebar <n> panels is impossible with the search engine because the bindings are not listed or described in any human readable manner. Instead it's some cryptic code, presumably Python, e.g. "space_data.show_region_ui"

Comment: @AaronF.Ross   see edit. I hope this is what you were after.